# MATLAB: Write a function that takes the name of a text file and returns a 2-dimensional array of the data in the file, skipping the first row of data?

Tags: matlab

a. I need help to write a function that takes the name of a tab delimited text file and returns a 2-dimensional array of the data in the file, skipping the first row of data?

b. Using the same function from the first part I need to write another function `maxMerge` that takes the name of two of these tab-delimited files and returns a single 2-dimensional array where each element of the array is the larger of the corresponding elements from the two data files.

I would appreciate any help....Thank You!

example:

```
file 1             file 2        maxMerge
0 0 0              0 0 0       
10 20 30           2 4 8         10 20 30
45 55 63           16 32 64      45 55 64
80 90 99           128 56 500    128 90 500
```

Answer (score 1):

This reads a little like homework so I'll point you in some directions. The [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) function will read the contents of a file. Have a look at the HeaderLines option for skipping the first row.

In the second part, you could do the following:

1. Use the function of the first part to load the two data files of size Nx2.
2. Concatenate the two loaded arrays so you have a Nx2x2 array.
3. Use the [MAX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/max.html) function with the dimension argument to find the maximum of the concatenated array along the 3rd dimension, i.e the dimension which designates unique data files.